# What does 'No file known for: classes2.dex' mean?

Tags: java, android

I built an app and I have different classes, and first I got an error like this when I tried to run the app

> Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 66087 > 65536)

I followed some instructions from Google and I added to my build.gradle

this dependency

> implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

and to the defaultConfig this

> multiDexEnabled true

In my manifest xml I added this

> ```
> android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
> ```

but its highlighted with red color and when I move the cursor over it says

> Unresolved class MultiDexApplication

When I try to run the app again it throws me

> No file known for: classes2.dex
>
> Known maps: {RelativeFile{base=/Users/***/AndroidStudioProjects/****/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug/mergeDexDebug/out/classes.dex, path=classes.dex, type=DIRECTORY}=classes.dex, RelativeFile{base=/Users/****/AndroidStudioProjects/****/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug/mergeProjectDexDebug/out/classes.dex, path=classes.dex, type=DIRECTORY}=classes3.dex, RelativeFile{base=/Users/*****/AndroidStudioProjects/****/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug/mergeExtDexDebug/out/classes2.dex, path=classes2.dex, type=DIRECTORY}=classes4.dex}

This is the MainActivity Class

```
package com.example.drivieapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         final Intent i = new Intent(this, screenNotLogged.class );
        Thread timer = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3100);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                   startActivity(i);
                   finish();

                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Can you please explain me what I have to do? I google the solution but didn't understand too much. Thank you very much!

Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="****">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Drivie"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

    >
        <activity android:name=".SignupCarrier"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".carrierSignupHint" />
        <activity android:name=".home" />
        <activity android:name=".SignupSender" />
        <activity android:name=".signup" />
        <activity android:name=".screenNotLogged" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest file? But I would guess you have to remove android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Comment: Yes, in a second!

Comment: did you try removing android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"? I don't have that in my application and multidex is working fine

Comment: Yes, let me remove it and I update the question with the log

Comment: It worked but before it didn't thank you very much !